# android - How to change textview maxLines in orientation change?

Tags: android, textview, landscape-portrait, screen-rotation

How to change textview maxLines in orientation mode change? For example, in portrait mode 4 maxlines, but in landscape 2 maxlines. i tried with below code, but not success, only in portrait mode its show 4 lines, but in landscape not show 2 lines:

MainActivity

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
          maxlines();
             case...
             default:
                        break;
                }
```

........................

```
private void maxlines(){
        if(getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
            arabicfont.setMaxLines(4);
        }else{
            if(getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE){
                arabicfont.setMaxLines(2);
            }
        }
    }
```

Manifest

```
<activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Comment: Override onConfigurationChanged in tour activity and to put maxlines on it

Comment: Once again question. How to do since 1st launch app, its recognize screen as a portrait? because, when 1st time launching app and i click on listview item, itsnot showing 4 maxlines (its fill all layout), but after landscape and then going back to portrait its showing 4 lines

Comment: @alizulfuqar call the maxlines() function from the onResume() method.

Comment: I want add to onCreate rather than onResume. Because resume is resume, i want launch app

Comment: @alizulfuqar Please refer to the lifecycle chart that I added in the answer section. onResume will also be launched when onCreate is launched.

Comment: Thanks for recommends

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to solve this method:

1) Overriding OnConfigurationChanged method: This method is called when the orientation of the device is changed.

2) Overriding OnResume method by calling the maxlines() function from that method: This method is called throughout the activity [lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle).